# .setText function causing errors

Tags: android, android-layout

The .setText Function on the text view is causing my application to crash. From what I've read the problem could be something about it not being on the UI thread but i have no idea how to fix it

```
public class SingleMenuItemActivity  extends Activity {

TextView lblName;
TextView lblyest;
TextView lbltoday;
TextView lblHigh;
TextView lblLow;
TextView lblChange;
TextView lblPcchange;
Button set;

String name, yesterday, today, high, low, change, pcchange;

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.single_list_item);

    set=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSet);
    lblName =   (TextView) findViewById( R.id.name );
    lblyest = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.yesterday );
    lbltoday = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.today );
    lblHigh = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.high );
    lblLow = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.low );
    lblChange = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.change );
    lblPcchange = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.pcchange );


    Intent in = getIntent();

    name = in.getStringExtra( "name" );
    ;
    yesterday = in.getStringExtra( "yesterday" );
    today = in.getStringExtra( "today" );
    high = in.getStringExtra( "high" );
    low = in.getStringExtra( "low" );
    change = in.getStringExtra( "change" );
    pcchange = in.getStringExtra( "pcchange" );


            lblName.setText(name);
            lblyest.setText(yesterday);
            lbltoday.setText(today);
            lblHigh.setText(high);
            lblLow.setText(low);
            lblChange.setText(change);
            lblPcchange.setText(pcchange); 




}


}
```

Can't figure out exactly what the problem is

Here is the **logcat :**

```
10-10 15:37:14.544: I/ActivityManager(58): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.kmarima.knight/.SingleMenuItemActivity (has extras) }
10-10 15:37:18.217: D/SntpClient(58): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
10-10 15:37:24.613: W/ActivityManager(58): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
10-10 15:37:24.685: W/ActivityManager(58): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{45018590 com.kmarima.knight/.SingleMenuItemActivity}
10-10 15:37:29.874: D/dalvikvm(264): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2061 objects / 147656 bytes in 165ms
10-10 15:37:34.914: D/dalvikvm(296): GC_EXPLICIT freed 811 objects / 56944 bytes in 162ms
```

And here is where the activity starts

```
             Intent in = new Intent(KnightActivity.this, SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
              in.putExtra("name", "The Name");
                 in.putExtra("yesterday", "Value For Yesterday");
                 in.putExtra("today", "Todays Value");
                 in.putExtra("high", "High Value");
                 in.putExtra("low", "Low Value");
                 in.putExtra("change", "Change Value");
                 in.putExtra("pcchange", "PC Change Value");

             startActivity(in);
```

Comment: Show your logcat error .

Comment: most probably your problem is not the setText but any of those values being null.You should do a if(value!=null) check before any of those set texts,also i would doublecheck what your intent returns

Comment: I don't think the problem is with setText(), but with the fact that one of the extra data is null (Do you receive a NullPointerException?)

Comment: just done a check .. the values arent Null

Comment: Can you show where you are sending the intent for starting the activity. It might be a problem that one of the strings is null.

Comment: Also, it is a good practice to declare keys as constants, so that you do not misspell it.

Answer (score 0):

in setText, you must be setting some null values. On which line its giving error ?
Please check variables are not null.

Answer (score 0):

you're getting this problem because  you are not getting the values from intent, must be one or more values will be null or you are using different keys on getting the values from intent, please check keys on both activities , are they same.

Answer (score 0):

```
You are getting this error because.....

"This exception is thrown when a program attempts to create an URL from an
incorrect specification."
```

Comment: You should provide the source of the quote

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if (extras == null) {
              return;
            }
 String name=extras.getString("name");
```

Instead of

```
Intent in = getIntent();

name = in.getStringExtra( "name" );
```